# Install GoPanda2 on Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I am trying to install GoPanda2 into Ubuntu. The download file is a tar.gz and can be found [here](http://www.panda-igs.com/communities/gopanda2).

I extracted the folder to my desktop and then used the terminal to run the `install.sh` file. When that process finished I still could not run the application.

This is the message from the terminal when running the `install.sh` file:

```
Installing GoPanda2 to /home/brett/.local/bin

cp: cannot stat ‘GoPanda2’: No such file or directory

cp: cannot stat ‘nw.pak’: No such file or directory

cp: cannot stat ‘libffmpegsumo.so’: No such file or directory

Installing desktop file to /home/brett/Desktop and /home/brett/.local/share/applications

cp: cannot stat ‘GoPanda2.desktop’: No such file or directory

cp: cannot stat ‘GoPanda2.desktop’: No such file or directory

Installing icon to /home/brett/.local/share/icons
cp: cannot stat ‘GoPanda2.png’: No such file or directory

Done!
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

First [download](http://pandanet-igs.com/communities/gopanda2) it , then do:

1- In a terminal window, extract the archive:

```
  tar xvf gopanda2-linux-??.tar.gz
```

2- Run the installation script

```
  ./install.sh
```

3 -Run the application by clicking on the icon or start it from the terminal
If you encounter a problem with libudev.so.0 (an issue with the node-webkit tool GoPanda2 is using), you need to create a link:

1- Find where libudev.so.1 is located (perhaps /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ or /usr/lib/) and cd to that directory

2- Create the link:

```
  sudo ln -s libudev.so.1 libudev.so.0
```

*[Source](http://pandanet-igs.com/communities/pandanet/11#start)*